# value of a field not coming into j query variable

Tags: jquery

I have a jquery function.inside which i wants a variable whose value is a value of coulamn of the table of same page.how I can get the value of that field into the variable.
suppose I have a coulamn  whose id is mktType. Now I define a variable in j query function how can i got the value of that mktType into j query variable

my j query function is 
$(document).ready(function(){

```
    alert($("#mktType.mktType").html());});
```

and my coulamn is

Comment: How are people supposed to help you with your code if you don't post your code?

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
 
 alert($("#mktType").val());
  
 } it is not working.

Comment: in this mktType is id of that coulamn..

Comment: @user3575287 `.val()` will not work for `table column` you have to use `.html()` or `.text()` `function`, see my answer below for reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var value = $('#mktType').html();
```

**[Demo Link](http://jsfiddle.net/manoj_admlab/S6Yfr/)**

Comment: @ Manoj: Yeah, or `.text()`, depending.

Comment: @ Manoj for html it is showing undefined and for text it is printing just blank..

Comment: @user3575287 Please add the `html markup` in your question, make sure your `id` is correct, demo link http://jsfiddle.net/manoj_admlab/S6Yfr/ added in answer

Comment: thnx @ Manoj it works..

Answer (score 0):

To get The value of mktType you need to use html() function

`var value = $('#mktType').html();` or

```
 $('#mktType').text();
```

Comment: When you see you've just duplicated a previous answer, the correct thing to do is to delete your duplicate.